# Dell Inspiron 15 Laptop Won't Wake From Sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, dell-inspiron

Before I get started, yes this is a duplicate question, but nothing from a of the other posts were resolving the problem.

So a little less than a year ago, I purchased this laptop, it's currently working fine except a couple beeps and startup due to the screen being broken, but it works fine on an external monitor.

I put it in Sleep mode (no, not hibernate or anything else) in Windows 10. Pressing the power button or any other keys will not wake it. I unplugged the charger, battery and plugged them back in many times. I've tried just charger, just battery and holding down the power button. I've even unplugged everything and waiting a couple hours, plugged it back in and still nothing.

The laptop will not wake and I have no other ideas on how to get it running again.

Any and all help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does the laptop make any sounds when it boots up?

Comment: I'm just wondering why you wouldn't use paragraphs and make this more readable?

Comment: Don Larynx- It used to, but it will not boot up at all now. No lights, no noise, nothing on the screen. The caps lock button, number lock, and scroll lock buttons do not turn the corresponding leds on on the keyboard either.

Comment: Xavierjazz- Is this better?

Comment: If it is under a year old you should consider returning it to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of Windows OS itself. So tuning power options of the OS is with limited help.

As of my experience, this is an issue with the Display Driver provided with Windows 10 for the Display Unit.

The driver won't let windows to wake when the laptop unfold.
The easiest and quick solution is try
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04?dgc=IR&cid=esupport&lid=3-1&ref=bnn%E2%80%8B
and update your drivers for BIOS and Display.

Or rollback the Windows 10 Display Driver with Windows 07 Display Driver available with the Vendor.

Comment: What makes you suspect that it is the display driver?

Comment: To be honest, None of the options described by other users with Power Options won't solve the problem. Yet Laptop itself is working fine and it worked with Windows 7 for wakey-sleepy folds. So the educated guess is drivers not working properly. I won't assume the BIOS having a problem with Windows OS, so trial and error with each driver that are to wake the Laptop. Then changing display driver solved the problem instead every other. So I can safely say that downgrading the Display Driver to Windows 7 mode or Updating the Driver from Dell itself (I did this way by the way) will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Inspirion 15 7000 gaming laptop. Rolling back the Intel display graphic drivers based on https://superuser.com/a/1265534/281664 solved it for me.

Comment: Can’t even start it now lol