# Windows 10 laptop screen messed up after sleeping

Tags: windows-10, display, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics

I got Dell Inspirion 7567 with nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and Intel HD 630.
Since today, loading after sleeping mode gets me to this:
[image: messed]

Complete reboot fixes it, but after that, I close laptop lid, re-open it and get same mess.

So I read about possible troubles after recent windows update [in case of GeForce video adapter](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/1026749/window-10-fall-creators-update-feedback-thread/?offset=463), reinstalled all GeForce software, including drivers, but it didn't helped.

I tried to switch off Intel HD from Device Manager. After that, sleep mode disappeared from start menu. After closing lid windows somehow "wakes up" to current state, with opened windows and running programs and without any troubles. But GTX 1050 also became unavailable after that. I rolled back and now confused: what are possible actions to locate a reason of this problem? I still suppose that is software problem, but currently I am not sure.

If any additional info needed, I would provide it.

Comment: I have a nearly new Inspiron 15 7000, and I'm now having exactly the same problem. It seems the latest intel display driver that Dell is pushing out is completely broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: The same day I posted this, Intel provided a new driver branch (15.60) which also appears to solve the problem from the initial version, 15.60.0.4849.

**TL;DR - if you use a built-in Intel graphics adapter, install 15.45.21.4821 from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88345), after checking it is compatible with your OS and adapter.**

For me, this seems to have been a problem with the drivers for the Intel HD 530 graphics built into my 6th gen Intel processor. Unlike other contributors, I don't have a Dell machine (and the "Rollback" button was disabled), so I went to the [Intel download site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88345) for my adapter. The drivers are more general than specific product numbers, so similar problems with other adapters might be solvable with the same drivers - you should obviously check compatibility before experimenting.

In the end, I used the latest driver from the 15.45 branch, (15.45.21.4821) which worked. At the time of writing, this was the latest *built* driver, but not the most recent branch. The latest 15.47 driver (15.47.02.4815) exhibited the same problems as the version included with the broken Windows update.

Intel's versioning is shocking: they list both branches 15.45. and 15.47 as "latest" with no indication (for Win 10) of how you choose one over the other. To make matters worse, once the drivers are installed they report a mostly different version number in device manager (21.20.16.4821, in the case of 15.45.21.4821).

Answer (score 3):

I have the same laptop and started having the same problem recently. I was able to roll back the Intel HD driver to version 21.20.16.4727 (from 21.20.16.4735) which appears to have solved the problem. You can download that version from the Dell website. http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=28VH9

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Can't verify your solution - just got another fix:
update BIOS driver for the laptop from Dell site:
http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/product-support/servicetag/2d6dx32/drivers
It helped.

Comment: This solution solved it for me! :) on an Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming laptop with the Intel 630.

Answer (score 0):

Roll back your display driver. Worked for me.
windows-x, choose device manager
open display adapter branch, right click on Intel HD Graphics, choose properties
click rollback driver button.
The new (bad) driver was dated 6/??/16 and the rolled back driver 4/22/16.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Rollback button is disabled, i suppose, there is no previous version of the driver in my OS.